# Jquery/Browser hangs when performing an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got an ecommerce site that takes payments over a payment gateway for credit cards. Customers enter their credit card details in and press submit, the system makes an API call using Jquery to the gateway and it responds with either a success or fail. This usually works but 1 out of every 10 times (randomly) it seems to just hang. Now I'm not sure if it is because the API is not returning something or the Jquery ajax call is playing up... is there a way to find out?

The gateway provider I am using is very reputable and I highly doubt it is a problem with their API. So I'm thinking it has something to do with my code. Could someone help me by suggesting how I could go about identifying the problem and debugging.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!! :)

Here's the code, its wrapped in the validate plugin...

```
$("#form_checkout").validate({
    focusCleanup: false,
    focusInvalid: true,
    onkeyup: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            alert("Looks like you have missed or made mistakes on "+errors+" fields");
        }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        // disable the place order button to stop customer from pressing it twice
        $("#button_place_order").fadeOut('fast',function() {
            $("#button_place_order_disabled").fadeIn('fast');
        });

        var aCheckoutForm = $("#form_checkout").serializeArray();

        // #nOrderId will only exist if user firstly submits, then navigates away from checkout and comes back
            $.post('/core/ajax/cart.ajax.php', { pAction: "checkout",
                                                     pOrderId: $("#nOrderId").val(),  
                                                     pCheckoutForm: aCheckoutForm }, 
                                                     function(data) {
            if (data != null && data.sSessionExists != 'N') {

                $("#nOrderId").val(data.nOrderId);

                // if payment is successful then go to receipt page
                if (data.TxnResult == 'true') {

                    if ($("#sPaymentType").val() == 'form_payment_paypal') {
                        window.location.replace('/front/paypal-link.php');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert ('Thank you, click OK to continue');                              
                        window.location.replace("/front/receipt.php?pOrderNumber="+data.sOrderNumber);
                    };

                }
                else {
                    // only allow 4 attempts at cc payment
                    maxCcTries = maxCcTries+1;
                    if (maxCcTries >= 4) {
                        alert ('All of your details have been recorded but the transactions were not successful, please contact us to complete your order');
                        window.location.replace("/logout.php");                 
                    }
                    else {
                        alert ('The credit card payment has failed, please check your details and try again.');
                        // re-enable the place order button if credit card details failed so customer can try again                     
                        $("#button_place_order_disabled").fadeOut('fast',function() {
                            $("#button_place_order").fadeIn('fast');
                        });
                    };
                }; // end txn result
            }
            else {
                // timeout
                alert ('Due to extended inactivity, your session has timed out. Please add products to your cart again');
                window.location.reload();
            }; // end session check

        }, "json"); // end post

        return false;
    }
}); // end form_checkout
```

Comment: Without the code as well as the contents of a JS console, hard (OK, impossible!) to tell what's going on.

Comment: hey guys, sorry i've added the code now

Comment: Any idea guys? I've posted the code as requested or is that not enough info?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this type of problem recently
and i found two problem ,
1. first your request/response is processed more while sending by third party addons  and any antivirus try to check your request.(this is a client side issue).

1. now problem with my gateway at my gateway one firewall is installed it checks request/response every time .

so i get response slow, i hope this will help you.

Comment: hey thanks for your response.. not sure i fully understand it tho